# reuse computated data from a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, workbench

First things first, i am new to SQL.
So I've got two tables **dept_emp** and **titles**.
My problem is that when I have a single select query like this, I need ~2secs(I am ok with that)

```
select  dept_no 
from dept_emp,titles
where titles.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
    and titles.title = 'Engineer'
group by dept_emp.dept_no
having count(*) < 1000);
```

When I use that as a subquery on something like that

```
select dept_emp.emp_no
from dept_emp
where dept_emp.dept_no in (
    select  dept_no 
    from dept_emp,titles
    where titles.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
        and titles.title = 'Engineer'
    group by dept_emp.dept_no
    having count(*) < 1000)
limit 10;
```

execution time goes around 100 sec.
If my limit goes on 1000+ data, then execution time goes to infinity..

What could I do to reuse  the data that I use from the subquery?
And lastly would be more efficient if I could convert that inner query to a join?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do not use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Instead, always use explicit join syntax, and note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is *almost* pointless, and unreliable. Finally, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: actually order by improved time by 20 seconds, but I dont think that I'll have great results on 100,1000+ data :/
Also I am checking out what you said about DDL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure dept_emp.dept_no is indexed (and (emp_no,title) too)...

```
SELECT x.emp_no
  FROM dept_emp x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT dept_no 
         FROM dept_emp de
         JOIN titles t   
           ON t.emp_no = de.emp_no
        WHERE t.title = 'Engineer'
        GROUP 
           BY de.dept_no
       HAVING COUNT(*) < 1000
     ) y
    ON y.dept_no = x.dept_no
 ORDER 
    BY emp_no
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: seems that worked pretty good.
I think that I've need to take a deep dive on indexes